# how to remove list element using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

If I have a dropdownlist with **two** list  elements as below then I want to remove the top one. I know this bit of code would remove the element `$('#DeliveryOptionId option:nth-child(1)').remove();` but how can we count the items before removing the first.thanks

```
 <select  id="DeliveryOptionId" name="DeliveryOptionId" class="valid">
    <option value="">Delivery options</option>
    <option value="1">Post article to me</option>
 </select>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `$('#DeliveryOptionId option').length` to check for length and then remove.

```
if($('#DeliveryOptionId  option').length > 1) {
    $('#DeliveryOptionId option:nth-child(1)').remove();
}
```

Comment: @ComFreek: Thanks mate, clicked the button a tad early :D

Comment: You don't even need `> 1` ;)

Comment: @ComFreek: Correct for that sample it is not needed. But I am not sure when the OP wants to remove the option. If the need is say to delete if there are more than 3 options (or some number like that) then the check for `>3` would be needed :)

Answer (score 3):

If you want to know the number of items in the select, use `length`:

```
var numberOfOptions = $('#DeliveryOptionId option').length;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#DeliveryOptionId option").length;
```

Comment: Please don't post the same answer as others have already done, instead, give upvotes to them.

Comment: or if you post the same code as someone else at the same time (happens all the time - 2 same answers at once), add some more explanation, example, JSFiddle etc. - that way you make your answer more valuable and possibly the one to be accepted

Comment: Okey, thanks for the tips. The other answers were posted while i was typing mine.

Answer (score 0):

`length` returns the number of jQuery elements found by the selector

```
var nr = $('#DeliveryOptionId option').length;
```

If you want to remove the first option use:

```
$('#DeliveryOptionId option').first().remove();
```

or

```
$('#DeliveryOptionId option:first').remove();
```

And if you want to remove the last use `last()` (or `:last`) instead of `first()` (or `:first`).